# HP Omen Laptop, can't launch Ubuntu installer for Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, nvidia, uefi

So I have crawled around the web for 2 days now, only to notice that I'm not the only one with this problem and not a single person really knows how to fix this. This is not a single good guide or video out there to solve this problem so here we go...

Computer Specs: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05609719 upgraded to 16 GB of ram and ia Samsung 970 Pro SSD is installed.

secure boot = disabled
TPM = Available / disabled
SGX = disabled
Legacy boot = disabled

I have installed Ubuntu on a live USB, verified the install and checked for bad blocks on the USB (3.0).

So when i insert the usb, the standard Grub loader comes up. I scrolled down to install ubuntu, and press E, then I go to the end of the following line:

> linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---

I have tried the follow additional commands:

nouveau.modeset=0
acpi=off
modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
nomodeset

None of this at any given time have worked.  After I press <kbd>F10</kbd> I see this error:

> failed to claim resource 1.
>   platform device creation failed: -16

My understanding is that it has something to do with NVIDIA drivers,
please help.

PS. Ubuntu why haven't you fixed this yet. It's been a plague since 16.04.

Comment: When booting with Live USB does "Try Ubuntu without installing" option function properly?i Some Live USBs will fail because of the program used to create them in Windows. How did you create the Live USB?

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling Legacy Boot: I had it enabled when I dual-booted my HP Omen with Ubuntu.
Also, you likely need to additionally pass the `pci=nommconf` as a command alongside the `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` that you already had. Without that argument, I also couldn't open the Ubuntu installer nor Ubuntu itself later.

I've written up all the steps I had to follow to successfully install Ubuntu alongside Windows on my HP Omen in this article: https://medium.com/@twinters/dual-booting-hp-omen-15-laptop-with-windows-10-ubuntu-276e19cc80dd

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Im just using WSL with a X-Server now.